# URL in ajax request in PHP MVC framework, don't know how?

Tags: php, jquery, json, model-view-controller, url

I have a problem with AJAX request in PHP MVC framework: I don't know how to call JSON formatted data from controller to the view using, for example, jQuery.

I wasted many hours searching for any useful tip on the internet and trying to resolve this problem by myself but with no success.

I think the problem is where I need to write the URL; I can't write it correctly.

This is the code for the controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=myframework;host=localhost', 'root', '');
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT variety ,fruit_id FROM fruit limit 10');
   $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   $stmt->execute();
   $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And this is the view code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8" /> </head>
 <h1>grid ajax</h1> <body>  <table id='grid'></table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo PROJECT_URL ?>/views/search/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$.getJSON( myURL - HERE IS PROBLEM ! , function(json){
 for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
 $('#grid').append("<tr><td>" + json[i].fruit_id + "</td><td>" + json[i].variety + "</td></tr>")
       }
    });
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is routing:

```
getUrlFor($controller = 'index', $action = 'index') { $route = array('controller' => $controller, 'action' => $action); $routes = $this->getRoutes(); $url = array_search($route, $routes); if ($url === false) { $url = $controller . '/' . $action; } $url = PROJECT_URL . '/' . $url; return $url; } }
```

and `public function urlFor()`:

```
public function urlFor($controller = 'index', $action = 'index')
{
    return Router::getInstance()->getUrlFor($controller, $action);
}
```

This function works in this framework everywere; 
URL form example: http://localhost/myframework/ajax/index,
(`var $myURL = "<?php echo $this->urlFor('ajax', 'index'); ?>";` - in jQuery I use it in this form), only not in `$.getJSON`. I tried to write this URL in many forms, none of them worked. It is simple custom framework.

Comment: how do you write url in that framework? also, your <h1> tag is outside <body> tag, and your <table> ends as soon as it begins; I strongly recommend to validate your html there

Comment: var $myURL = "<?php echo $this->urlFor('ajax', 'index'); ?>"; in this form

Comment: function from router: public function getUrlFor($controller = 'index', $action = 'index')
    {
        $route = array('controller' => $controller, 'action' => $action);
        $routes = $this->getRoutes();
        $url = array_search($route, $routes);
        if ($url === false) {
            $url = $controller . '/' . $action;
        }
        $url = PROJECT_URL . '/' . $url;
        return $url;
    }
}

Comment: don't post code in comments, is difficult to read; update your question instead! Also, you didn't say if this is a custom framework or what? (Kohana?)

Comment: ok sorry Damien, it is custom framework

Comment: Question repetition is not acceptable on Stack Overflow, please update or improve this question, do do ask another question asking for help with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your routing is setup so can't offer specific help. But what I usually do is (I use [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/)) make a separate controller for all ajax calls. The functions in the controller gets the data from the model, passes that data to the view and servers the view to the ajax request.

Codeigniter has (imo) very nice routing, you call the ajax controller with the url

`http://sitename.com/index.php/controller_name/function`

and that's what you pass the the ajax call

```
$.getJSON( 'http://sitename.com/index.php/controller_name/function' , function(json){
 for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
 $('#grid').append("<tr><td>" + json[i].fruit_id + "</td><td>" + json[i].variety + "</td></tr>")
       }
    });
```

Hope this helps at all.

Comment: thanks Zelijko but it is not Codeigniter, i know in Codeigniter this thing is simple, but here is problem, routing is here: public function getUrlFor($controller = 'index', $action = 'index') { $route = array('controller' => $controller, 'action' => $action); $routes = $this->getRoutes(); $url = array_search($route, $routes); if ($url === false) { $url = $controller . '/' . $action; } $url = PROJECT_URL . '/' . $url; return $url; } }

Comment: Can you post a sample url from this site. Just so I can figure out the url structure. Looking at getUrlFor() it looks to me the url maybe similar to codigniter, projecturl/controller/action.